# My Flutter Application is showing error when i tried to run in android mobile or an emulator

Tags: android, flutter, mobile

This is Error

Every flutter project show this kind of error when i tried to launch in emulator but it gets run in chrome. I tried to change different dependencies but do not work it only shows this error again and again

```
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX3511 in debug mode...
[Fatal Error] guava-28.1-jre.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] gson-2.8.5.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.     
[Fatal Error] jsr305-1.3.9.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.   

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'E:\flutter\flutter\final project\downwork\android\app\build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration 'classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.guava:guava:28.1-jre.
```

This is my build.grade file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace all :

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
```

to:

```
repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
```